# Drawing multiple solid color squares in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

How can I form one image containing two squares in matlab from a 3 * 2 matrix containing the RGB values?
eg: [image: display something like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RGB = [255 0; 0 255; 0 0]; % red and green
rectSize = 50;

imshow([repmat(reshape(RGB(:,1),[1 1 3]),[rectSize rectSize]) repmat(reshape(RGB(:,2),[1 1  3]),[rectSize rectSize])]);
```

[image]